# How to use struct in c?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct, free

Here is my code:

```
struct Point
{
    int i;
    int j;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int a;
    int b;
    for(a = 0; a < n; a++)
    {
        for(b = a+1; b < n; b++)
        {
            struct Point *data = (struct Point *) malloc(sizeof(struct Point));
            data.i = a;
            data.j = b;
            // do something here
            free(data);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I got an error at `data.i = a;` and `data.j = b;`:

```
error: request for member 'i' in something not a structure or union
error: request for member 'j' in something not a structure or union
```

How can I fix this error?

Also, should I use `free()` after `malloc(sizeof(struct Point))`?

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to `malloc` (and thus, don't need to `free`) if you don't need the values after the current iteration ended. You can simply use `struct Point data;` and assign the members as you do now.

Comment: @delnan Actually, I use it in another thread, so I had to use `malloc`

Comment: You're not comfortable with pointers and dynamically memory allocation and you use threads?!?

Comment: @delnan I am a Java programmer, so I am not familiar with pointers at all.

Comment: `data->i` is a shortcut to the way where you dereference the pointer (to get an object of the specific struct type) before accessing its member with the `.` operator: `(*data).i`.

Comment: This probably shouldn't be marked C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` is a pointer. You have to say `data->i` etc. Only call `free()` when you no longer need the data structure.

Answer (score 2):

`data` is a pointer to a struct, not an actual struct. You should use `data->i` instead.

And yes, if you `malloc()` a struct, then you should `free()` it when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, a little explanation:

You have a pointer to a struct. First, you should dereference it, with the star operator, and then you can use it. The "->" operator is the abbreviated form of "*v." where v is a pointer to a struct. So you have `data->i` which is equivalent to `*data.i`

Comment: No, `(*data).i` is equivalent to `data->i`. What you wrote is equivalent to `*(data.i)`